# Data Cleansing in spark using spark sql and scala- handling encoded character

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i am getting file from API in .csv format, one of the address column containg encoded values like

```
(z$üíõ$F|'.h*Ë!øì=(.î;      
Þ.Í×áþ»¯ÁÍ¨
(k$üíõ$F|'.r*Ë!øì=(.î;  
    Koæice
```

But when it read in spark it is appearing like

```
�����������������������������
```

This we can do when we use spark 2.2

```
.option("encoding", "UTF-8")
```

But i am using spark 1.6, can any one please help me if any such option available in spark 1.6

In Code i did like

```
WHERE COL LIKE "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
```

But then output is 0 record

is there any way to exclude entire rows if any of the column these kind of non-alphabets string or number in Spark. i am using scala and spark sql .

**any such library or function to handle encoded values.**

Spark Version : 1.6

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

something like that:

```
val data = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("data/baddata.csv")
data.show()

data.filter(s=>s.getString(1).matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")).show()
```

and using udf:

```
val correctString: String => Boolean = _.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val correctStringUDF = udf(correctString)

data.filter(correctStringUDF('data)).show()
```

result:

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|                data|
+---+--------------------+
|  0|             correct|
|  1|(z$üíõ$F|'.h*Ë!øì...|
|  2|         Þ.Í×áþ»¯ÁÍ¨|
|  3|(k$üíõ$F|'.r*Ë!øì...|
|  4|              Koæice|
|  5|                  ok|
|  6|            ok ok ok|
+---+--------------------+

+---+-------+
| id|   data|
+---+-------+
|  0|correct|
|  5|     ok|
+---+-------+

+---+-------+
| id|   data|
+---+-------+
|  0|correct|
|  5|     ok|
+---+-------+
```

you can also achieve this using rdd

```
  val rddData = data.select('data)
    .map(_.getString(0))
    .rdd
    .filter(_.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, will this also work in spark 1.6, Please suggest

Comment: I've added example with rdd, it should work in spark 1.6